# C++ Memory Leak -- Need peer review

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

I have a pretty big leak somewhere in this screencapture code I have.

My C++ is pretty bad so if anyone can point out the issues that would be fantastic!

Here's the offending code:

```
FString AWindow::CaptureWindow(HWND hwnd) {

HDC hdcSrc = GetWindowDC(hwnd);
RECT rawRect;
LPRECT rect = &rawRect;

GetWindowRect(hwnd, rect);

int width = rect->right - rect->left;
int height = rect->bottom - rect->top;

HDC hdcDest = CreateCompatibleDC(hdcSrc);
HBITMAP hBitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdcSrc, width, height);

HGDIOBJ h0ld = SelectObject(hdcDest, hBitmap);
BitBlt(hdcDest, 0, 0, width, height, hdcSrc, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
SelectObject(hdcDest, h0ld);
DeleteDC(hdcDest);

    char* pImage = NULL;
    pImage = (char*)GlobalLock(hBitmap);


BITMAP bmp;
PBITMAPINFO pbmi;
WORD cClrBits;

GetObject(hBitmap, sizeof(BITMAP), (LPSTR)&bmp);

//Convert the color format to a count of bits
cClrBits = (WORD)(bmp.bmPlanes * bmp.bmBitsPixel);

if (cClrBits == 1)
    cClrBits = 1;
else if (cClrBits <= 4)
    cClrBits = 4;
else if (cClrBits <= 8)
    cClrBits = 8;
else if (cClrBits <= 16)
    cClrBits = 16;
else if (cClrBits <= 24)
    cClrBits = 24;
else cClrBits = 32;

//Allocate memory for the BITMAPINFO structure.
if (cClrBits < 24) {
    pbmi = (PBITMAPINFO)LocalAlloc(LPTR, sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER) + sizeof(RGBQUAD) * (1i64 << cClrBits));
}
else {
    pbmi = (PBITMAPINFO)LocalAlloc(LPTR, sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER));
}

//Initialize the field in the BITMAPINFO structure
pbmi->bmiHeader.biWidth = bmp.bmWidth;
pbmi->bmiHeader.biHeight = bmp.bmHeight;
pbmi->bmiHeader.biPlanes = bmp.bmPlanes;
pbmi->bmiHeader.biBitCount = bmp.bmBitsPixel;
pbmi->bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
pbmi->bmiHeader.biClrUsed = (1i64 << cClrBits);

pbmi->bmiHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;

//Computer the number of bytes in the array of color
//indices and store the result in biSizeImage.
pbmi->bmiHeader.biSizeImage = ((pbmi->bmiHeader.biWidth * cClrBits + 31) & ~31) / 8
    * pbmi->bmiHeader.biHeight;

//Set biClrImportant to 0, indicating that all of the device
//colors are important
pbmi->bmiHeader.biClrImportant = 0;

FString file = FPaths::Combine(*FPaths::GameDir(), TEXT("ScreenGrab/"), TEXT("Desktop.bmp"));

std::string mystring(TCHAR_TO_UTF8(*file));
std::wstring lpstring = std::wstring(mystring.begin(), mystring.end());
LPCWSTR realfile = lpstring.c_str();

FString error = CreateBMPFile(hwnd, realfile, pbmi, hBitmap, hdcSrc);

ReleaseDC(hwnd, hdcSrc);
DeleteObject(hBitmap);
return error;
```

}

I'm guessing there's some objects in there I'm forgetting to delete though I have no idea which ones they are.

Posting it here while I comment code out lines at a time to see if I can pinpoint the offending things.

Thanks
-Paul

::EDIT::

Upon further inspection I narrowed the severe leak down to the function saving the BMP.

Here that is:

```
FString AWindow::CreateBMPFile(HWND hwnd, LPCWSTR pszFile, PBITMAPINFO pbi, HBITMAP hBMP, HDC hDC) {
HANDLE hf;                 // file handle  
BITMAPFILEHEADER hdr;       // bitmap file-header  
PBITMAPINFOHEADER pbih;     // bitmap info-header  
LPBYTE lpBits;              // memory pointer  
DWORD dwTotal;              // total count of bytes  
DWORD cb;                   // incremental count of bytes  
BYTE *hp;                   // byte pointer  
DWORD dwTmp;

pbih = (PBITMAPINFOHEADER)pbi;
lpBits = (LPBYTE)GlobalAlloc(GMEM_FIXED, pbih->biSizeImage);

if (!lpBits) {
    return FString("global alloc failed");
}


// Retrieve the color table (RGBQUAD array) and the bits  
// (array of palette indices) from the DIB.  
if (!GetDIBits(hDC, hBMP, 0, (WORD)pbih->biHeight, lpBits, pbi,
    DIB_RGB_COLORS))
{
    return FString("get di bits failed");
}

// Create the .BMP file.  
hf = CreateFile(pszFile,
    GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
    (DWORD)0,
    NULL,
    CREATE_ALWAYS,
    FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
    (HANDLE)NULL);
if (hf == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    return FString("invalid file handle");
}
hdr.bfType = 0x4d42;        // 0x42 = "B" 0x4d = "M"  
                            // Compute the size of the entire file.  
hdr.bfSize = (DWORD)(sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER) +
    pbih->biSize + pbih->biClrUsed
    * sizeof(RGBQUAD) + pbih->biSizeImage);
hdr.bfReserved1 = 0;
hdr.bfReserved2 = 0;

// Compute the offset to the array of color indices.  
hdr.bfOffBits = (DWORD) sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER) +
    pbih->biSize + pbih->biClrUsed
    * sizeof(RGBQUAD);

// Copy the BITMAPFILEHEADER into the .BMP file.  
if (!WriteFile(hf, (LPVOID)&hdr, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER),
    (LPDWORD)&dwTmp, NULL))
{
    return FString("Write header failed");
}

// Copy the BITMAPINFOHEADER and RGBQUAD array into the file.  
if (!WriteFile(hf, (LPVOID)pbih, sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER)
    + pbih->biClrUsed * sizeof(RGBQUAD),
    (LPDWORD)&dwTmp, (NULL))) {
    return FString("write info header failed");
}


// Copy the array of color indices into the .BMP file.  
dwTotal = cb = pbih->biSizeImage;
hp = lpBits;
if (!WriteFile(hf, (LPSTR)hp, (int)cb, (LPDWORD)&dwTmp, NULL)) {
    return FString("copy color failed");
}

// Close the .BMP file.  
if (!CloseHandle(hf))


    // Free memory.  
    GlobalFree((HGLOBAL)lpBits);

return FString("Completed ok?");
```

}

Thanks again for any help! Digital brownies for anyone who solves this mess!

Comment: Consider using smart pointers (with custom deleters) to free and close your resources. That frees you from having to manage it manually everywhere.

Comment: Btw, this question would be better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Oh, didnt know codereview was a thing. I was wondering why all the down votes.

I'm not sure how compatible smart pointers are with Unreal Engine but I'll keep them in mind as I move forward :)

Comment: @JesperJuhl  Bjarne would be proud of your RAII comment. :)  NOTE: the GlobalAlloc and CreateFile need RAII.

Comment: `TCHAR_TO_UTF8(*file)` This doesn't make sense. You should use UTF16 in Windows. For example `std::wstring s = L"c:\\temp\\filename.bmp";` You shouldn't need any conversion here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "pbmi" was locally allocated.

You forgot to use "LocalFree" to release the allocation.

Maybe there are more, but that was the first one I spotted.

Comment: Thanks! Made the change!

I actually narrowed down the severe leak even further to the CreateBMPFile, which I'm adding to an edit at the bottom of the post.

Mind taking a look? (the function gets called a whole bunch in succession and quickly ammasses MB up MB of memory)

Comment: You need to GlobalFree before every return, it saves up a lot of memory. Just make sure you don't free twice.

Comment: Oh and one more thing, Use CloseHandle before every return - The handle will stay open, and that causes leaks.

Comment: Thanks! I read you reply and went through it all.

Found the main culprit (and have updated my code with the other changes aswell)

I needed to free(hp) before every return as well. Even though hp was point to the global alloc it was keeping memory

Answer (score 0):

Using [RAII](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii) (resource acquistion is initialization) pattern, you don't have to sprinkle closes and frees before each return.  Furthermore, you will prevent leaks if an exception is thrown (e.g. bad character encoding in UTF8 translation). Here is the idiom that @JesperJuhl is referring to in context of your code:

```
using file_raii_t = std::unique_ptr<std::remove_pointer<HANDLE>::type, decltype(&::CloseHandle)>;
using gmem_raii_t = std::unique_ptr<std::remove_pointer<HGLOBAL>::type, decltype(&::GlobalFree)>;

gmem_raii_t gmem(::GlobalAlloc(GMEM_FIXED, size), ::GlobalFree);
// gmem can be used like (!GetDIBits(..., gmem.get(), ...);

file_raii_t fh(::CreateFile(pszFile, GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, (DWORD)0, NULL,
    CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, (HANDLE)NULL), ::CloseHandle);
//fh can be used like FileRead(fh.get()...);
```

This can be extended to include other APIs (even APIs that return resources as out parameters). In you case: GetWindowDC, LocalAlloc.  Using RAII you can write fewer lines of exception-safe code.

Note: code from my aging memory. not tested in your code.